# Plotting individual bar graphs for each index of a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a a pandas data frame as follows with the index a;

```
                  b         c         d         e         f         g
a                                                                       
-2.447948  0.170758  1.246046 -1.452076  1.248984 -0.010419  0.980928   
 0.038355  0.106015  0.173747  0.934379  0.485859 -0.192508 -0.899376   
-0.584441 -0.384552  0.187411 -1.109639  1.529889 -0.059522  0.319147   
 1.883600  1.211055  1.434066  0.456128  0.456872 -0.575694 -0.741435   
 0.351659  1.230753  2.026344  0.303135  2.356994 -0.818239  0.346594   
 0.665147 -0.449289  0.607148  0.584124  0.007701 -1.663303 -0.127717   
-1.539684 -0.356195 -0.986359  1.292305  0.675561  0.279108 -1.561347   
 1.436973  1.787788  1.444885 -0.359050  1.069496  0.517877 -1.133649   
-0.317525 -1.101251 -0.146702  0.890189  1.323071  2.246965  0.706875   
 1.982059  0.144313 -0.014548 -0.300521 -0.583273  0.424427 -0.329592
```

b-g are columns. I was wondering if it's possible to write a script that plots a separate bar graph for every index? The problem is the data frame can very in size and therefore can have a different number of indexes every time the script is run, therefore I can't specify the index.

I was wondering if you could do this via iterating through the Data frame? Or even creating separate data frames for each index and plotting each.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

```
for i in df.T.index:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    df.T.ix[i].plot.bar(ax=ax)
```

**OLD answer:**

try something like this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

df.T.plot.bar(subplots=True)
```

[image]

Comment: That's an interesting idea. However all graphs are plotted on the same figure, I was wondering if there was any way to plot separate figures for each? Any other suggestions would also be great

Comment: @mjr14, please check "UPDATE" in my answer

Comment: Thank you that works a treat! Just out of curiosity do you think matplotlib's the best plotting library in python for data visualisation? Or could you recommend any others

Comment: I've played about with seaborn so will look into it further. I have another question, do you know how to prevent any x value that has a y value of 0 from being plotted? (to stop these from being shown on the graph?)